# Strange trouble with javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding

I have one simple code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        var f = $(this).closest('form');
        if(f != null){
            $(f).append('<div class="loadmask"></div>');                        
        }
    });
});
```

as you can see, I want to append a div with class 'loadmask' to the parent form. The strange thing here `$(f).append('<div class="loadmask"></div>');` had been encoded to  `$(f).append("<div class="loadmask"></div>&#34;);` and throws a javascript error.

**UPDATE:**

I have change my code to

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
            $(".button").click(function(){
                $(this).parent('form').append("<div class='loadmask'></div>");
            });
         });
```

still get javascript error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]   

$(this).parent('form').append("<div class="loadmask"></div>&#34;);
```

and at eclipse console:

```
00:57:17,593 ERROR [MinifierUtil:108] 22: 65: missing ) after argument list
00:57:17,593 ERROR [MinifierUtil:108] 22: 79: unterminated string literal
00:57:17,593 ERROR [MinifierUtil:108] 1: 0: Compilation produced 2 syntax errors.
00:57:17,593 ERROR [MinifierUtil:74] JavaScript Minifier failed for  


         $(document).ready(function(){          
            $(".button").click(function(){
                $(this).parent('form').append("<div class="loadmask"></div>&#34;);
            });
         });
```

I use eclipse Juno (ecoding project with UTF-8), liferay 6.1 ga-1 and jsf-2.0, icefaces-3 ....

Comment: Check the closing quotes `'`. Did you copy paste it from somewhere? &#34; translates to "

Comment: What is the JavaScript error that you get?

Comment: You could consider using .parents() instead of .closest().
Here's why - closest() tests the element itself and then traverses upwards through its ancestors in the DOM tree; while parents() immediately skips checking the element itself and directly starts evaluating the parents for a match.

Comment: @jsalonen: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
[Break On This Error]  

$(f).append('<div class="loadmask"></div>&#39;);

Comment: @kayen I dont use copy & past, I typed it

Comment: @KentPawar Or you could use `$("input").prop("form")` :)

Comment: @alex I took a look at <some element instance>.[prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)(PropertyName) .. It works a bit differently then your example: The .prop() method gets the property value for only the first element in the matched set. So your example is looking for the first input tag that has an attribute called form.

Comment: @Kent that's not correct. It gets a reference to the form of the first input selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really dont know why, but it seem that my xhtml (jsf2.0) can not decode html char inside script code.

(& symbol on && operator will raise the same error)

just change

`$(this).parent('form').append("<div class="loadmask"></div>");` to `$(this).parent('form').append("div").addClass("loadmask");`

and with &, use a child if statement instead of && will solve its issue.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your problem. What I suspect is that for some reason there is an additional character encoded in your JavaScript file that gets represented as `&#34;` by jQuery. `&#34` happens to be [the entity for quotation mark](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) (`"`) so make sure you don't have that as an extra in your code. Try cleaning your JavaScript source file and try again.

Also note that `closest` never returns `null`. If `form` element is not found, an empty list is returned (this can be easily verified by running the code on a formless page). Thus you could safely write your code simply as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        $(this).closest('form').append('<div class="loadmask"></div>');
    });
});
```

See this Fiddle for a proof: http://jsfiddle.net/p48Rb/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `if (f.length)`, because `$(this).closest('form')` returns a jQuery object which either has length > 0 (form is the first element) or not (length 0 evaluates to `falsy`). In other words, `f` is never `null`.